# What does Litho's @FromPrepare annotation do?

Tags: android, facebook, litho

I have been reading Litho's documentation and I found this code example

```
@LayoutSpec(events = { ColorChangedEvent.class })
class ColorComponentSpec {
  ...
  @OnCreateLayout
  static ComponentLayout onCreateLayout(
      Context c,
      @Prop EventHandler colorChangedHandler,
      @FromPrepare int color) {
    ...
    ColorComponent.dispatchColorChangedEvent(
        colorChangedHandler,
        color);
    ...
  }
}
```

What does the @FromPrepare annotation do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: this is an error in the docs. `@FromPrepare` should only be used in MountSpecs, not in LayoutSpecs.

`@FromPrepare` gives you an output that was returned from the `OnPrepare` method. You can read more about this pattern here: http://fblitho.com/docs/mount-specs#inter-stage-inputs-and-outputs

Comment: We've now removed this from the docs: https://github.com/facebook/litho/commit/872539968179b5cea46bde8cc813a0117d24f452